# canvas по центру при полноэкранном режиме

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, canvas

Я пытаюсь позиционировать элемент Canvas по центру вертикально и горизонтально, но после того как я нажимаю F11 и вкладка разворачивается на весь экран, я получаю ненормальное поведение. Я жму на кнопки внутри канваса, но ничего не происходит. Я начинаю искать эти кнопки кликая выше и ниже кнопки и получается так, что оно реагирует на нажатие там, где были кнопки до разворачивания вкладки на весь экран.
Есть какой-то способ как сделать канвас по центру, чтоб в полноэкранном режиме тоже всё хорошо работало?

Comment: Вы хоть разметку свою покажите.

Comment: так просто canvas, просто внутри тэга body. Я могу как угодно изменить, возможно вообще как-то сделать так, чтоб canvas был по ценру вертикально и при этом при переходе на полноэкранный режим не получать такое баг? Я сейчас пробую центрировать через position absolute и margin 0 auto.

Comment: Проще всего через `justify-content` + `align-items` вместе с `grid` или `flex`.